# Eclipse doesn't show Java reference suggestions

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse 2023-03. Used previous versions of it earlier. From the start, when I type a class, e.g. `List myList;` Eclipse gives suggestions such as java.util.List should be imported and allows me to click on that suggestion and Eclipse would insert the import statement.

On a fresh project where I am learning Maven, it is not doing that. Just says that List cannot be resolved to a type. The quick fixes in that popup doesn't show the option for importing the relevant package.

I have one of my old projects open in that same workspace and import suggestions are working there. Same Eclipse, same workspace.

What could be the matter?